# Unable to get overflow to scroll left/up, only right/down when dragging object

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have some divs that I'm dragging around with jQuery-ui. I have a small 500x500 area where this should be possible. When I drag to the right side off screen, x =1000,  the page will scroll to the right. If I drag to the bottom off screen, y=750, the page will scroll. This won't happen if I drag off screen to the top/left though (-1000/-750). The page will only expand/scroll to the right/bottom. Is it possible to have the page expand up/left, and not just down/right?

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="mainArea">
        <div class="object1Container">
          <div class="object1"></div>
          <div class="object1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <button> don't go past this</button>
      </div>

</div>

.object1{
  height:25px;
  width:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:red;
}

.mainArea{
  position:relative;
  background:green;
  height:100%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
.footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
.container{
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
  position:relative;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ADCrQDVHD8ZnT3X3WaPR?p=preview

Comment: I tried dragging one part a ways to the bottom-right, then scrolling back, then dragging the other one down-right, then up-left. Seems to be working okay for me.

Comment: Could you give us specific instructions on what you're trying, please?

Comment: Edited OP. I mean that the area is just 500x500. If I try to drag the object to x=1000, the page will scroll to the right so I can still see the object. I want to drag the object to x=-1000, but the page won't scroll to the left.

Comment: Ah, okay. I think that's expected behaviour. If you think of a scrollable div as a window, it wouldn't make sense to show elements that push left of the left size of the window, or up of the top side of the window. But the contents of the page (or the div) will naturally push down or right, so the window (and scrollbars) have to compensate.

Comment: The scrolling behaviour isn't a case of "make sure the mouse can be seen" or "make sure we can see every child element." It's more like "let's reflow the page so that the content still follows the css."

Comment: It's hard to explain, but that's how I understand it to work.

Comment: So is the behavior I want just not possible?

Comment: If what you want is to be able to drag an element off into infinity (left or up) and have the scrollbars keep up, then I'd say it's not possible. If you just want to be able to drag them within a certain space (say 100px beyond the div in any direction), then that should be possible.

Comment: Since all elements are TOP LEFT based, you have to do a little more work to scroll left and up. Basically, you have to resize the container. In a sense when you move the draggable upward, across a specific point, it's growing the box taller and pushing it down. For the left, you are making it wider. Make sense?